# Presentation of abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-presentation

How one can find the abelian group which has a presentation $$\langle x,y,z,w\mid6x+8y+10z+14w, 4x+4y+4z+4w\rangle$$ 
Is there any way indicates the steps to find such a group? Or just by guesswork and experience?

Edit: Can one proves directly whether it is the group $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ or not?

Comment: Yes one may calculate the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Comment: @Myself: As I have seen, this method works when $G=\langle X| R\rangle$, such that $|X|-|R|\le 0$.

Comment: @BabakS. What you say does not make sense. One can always reduce $|X|-|R|$ by simply introducing redundant relators. For example, $[x, y], [x, y^{-1}], [x^{-1}, y], [x^{-1}, y^{-1}], [y, x], [y, x^{-1}], \ldots$ all follow from $[x, y]$.

Comment: i think i found similar example which used Smith normal form to find out the group. http://books.google.se/books?id=BecLeCWOjI4C&pg=PA73&lpg=PP1&dq=Symmetries++By+D.+L.+Johnson page 73

Comment: (@BabakS. Perhaps you mean the deficiency of a group $G$? This is defined to be the maximum which $|X|-|R|$ can be for any presentation $G\cong\langle X; R\rangle$.)

Comment: @user1729: No, you noted right. In fact, your remark reminded me the points which I saw in Todd-Coxeter Algorithm. There; sometimes, I added some redundant relations. I got my bad mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The smith normal form of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
is
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
so your group is isomorphic to
$$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z.$$