# How to reconcile two different computed first homology groups for this space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

I am asked to classify the compact surface obtained by pasting the edges of a polygonal region with the labeling scheme $abcdabdc$ and compute it's first homology group. I classify the space as the connected sum of 3 real projective planes using cutting and pasting. (A quick algebraic check: call our scheme $w$ and let $e = abd$. Then $w = abcb^{-1}a^{-1}e^2c$. Let $f = b^{-1}a^{-1}e^2c$, then $w = abe^{-2}abf^2$. Let $g = e^{-2}ab$, then $w = e^2g^2f^2$ so our space can be classified as the connected sum of 3 projective planes).

The first homology group of the $n$-fold connected sum of real projective planes is known to be $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ (see here: [Homology of connected sum of real projective spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652721/homology-of-connected-sum-of-real-projective-spaces)) so I deduce $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now consider $H_1(X)$ as the abelianization of the fundamental group $\pi_1(X) \cong \langle a, b, c, d | abcdabdc = 1\rangle$. Then $H_1(X) \cong \text{Ab}(\pi_1(X)) \cong \langle a, b, c, d |2(a+b+c+d)=0 \rangle$. This representation is justified here: [Presentation of the abelianization of $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982136/presentation-of-the-abelianization-of-g) If we consider the generators of this presentation to be $\{a, b, c, a+b+c+d\}$ it seems clear that $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. (If you're not convinced that this manipulation on the generators is correct it is also shown here [Presentation of abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439014/presentation-of-abelian-group) that we can use the Smith Normal Form which gives the same result).

Clearly $\mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \ne \mathbb{Z}^3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ so what went wrong?

Comment: Doesn't $acdadc$ give the same surface?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Good point, yes it does if you substitute $a = ab$ in which case the abelianization method above gives the correct result. Is it true then that you always have to make those types of substitutions before abelianizing in that way?

Comment: In your presentation, $a$ and $b$ do not represent loops in the surface.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Of course, if I had labeled the vertices on the polygon it would have been clear. The vertex where $a$ meets $b$ is distinct from the rest so it's not a loop. Thank you. If you make that an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you identify your edges of an octagon in the pattern $abcdabdc$
then its eight vertices are identified into two points $P$ and $Q$ say,
where $Q$ is the image of the vertices between the $a$ and $b$ edges and $P$
is the images of the other six vertices. Therefore the edges $a$ and $b$ are not
mapped into loops in the surface, but $c$ and $d$ are mapped to loops based
at $P$. If we replace the $ab$ pairs of edges with edges labelled $e$, say,
then $e$ becomes a loop in the surface, and the fundamental group
is $\langle c,d,e\mid ecdedc=1\rangle$, Abelianising to $\Bbb Z_2
\oplus\Bbb Z^2$.